# How would i store the contents of a file without storing them on the db or server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just want the form to read the contents of the .csv file without storing them anywhere and perform this

```
csv_text = File.read('thefiletheychoose') # If this line isnt possible can we store the contents of the csv temp somewhere?
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
  Company.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
end
```

I have no clue what the .html would look like for this

Comment: When you get a file in a form submit you don't necessarily have to save it somewhere. You can just read it in-memory and ditch when you're done.

Comment: You want's to do it on client side?

Comment: If possible yes, how would i about doing that forker at the moment all i have set up is a test csv controller with a index page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have a file upload field in your form:

```
<%= form_tag '/companies/create', :multipart => true do %>
  <label for="file">File to Upload</label>
  <%= file_field_tag "upload" %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

You should do the following in the controller:

```
def create
  csv_text = params[:upload].read
  # Same thing as yours:
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
  csv.each do |row|
    row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
    Company.create!(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
  end
end
```

Comment: On the controller im getting a undefined method `read', also how would i put the file_field into a form the one i have seems to not be working

Comment: You should change '/companies/create' to the appropriate controller/action url you have. And don't forget that you should have a proper url mapping in `config/routes.rb`, like `post '/companies/create' => 'companies#create'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use tempfile: http://apidock.com/ruby/Tempfile